# Modern AJAX Webapp Paradigm

Tags: java, javascript, json, web-applications, asp-classic

**Introduction:**

My company has a webapp based on classic ASP. As our webapp grows, we are finding it difficult to maintain the system. I feel that the complexity of the code and the need for many ASP pages are making the maintenance of the system outweigh the development of new features. I have some thoughts on how to modernize the system, and I would appreciate the community's feedback on how modern webapps work.

**Question:**

My current understanding is that there are two major portions to the architecture of a modern webapp. There is the front end (browser/user facing) and the back end (server/database). In our current ASP architecture, the backend and data requests from the database are mashed together with our client side code. I feel that there should be separation between the two components, and that JSON is that solution.

The picture below demonstrates the architecture that I envision:
[image: Architecture concept]

My idea is to have the front end developers and back end developers work by agreeing on some sort of "API". For example, lets say the business requirements say that we need to send a list of current customers.

Front end developer: I need to display a list of the customers to the user.

Back end developer: I need to get a list of the customers from the database, and send this to the front end developers.

The JSON would look something like this:

```
[
    {
        "fname": "John",
        "lname": "Doe",
        "price": "5"
    },
    {
        "fname": "Jane",
        "lname": "Deer",
        "price": "5"
    }
]
```

**How I Envision This Working**

Front End Code:

Assumptions: Single page app, All requests go to one server page, Javascript with JQuery, Knockout.js

```
//AJAX request for data using jQuery and GET request
$.getJSON('/index',         //The page where I request data from
    {"request":"customers"} //JSON to let server know what I want
    , function(data) {      //Function to execute
    //Get the data in the pre-defined format
    //Add to MVVM (knockout.js)
    someKnockoutMappingFunction();
});
```

Back End Code:

Assumptions: Java

```
 String request = req.getParameter("request");
    if (request == null) {
       //Error case
    }
    //The AJAX request came in requesting customers
    else if(request == "customers")
    {
        //Get the data from the database and format it
        someDatabaseToJSONFunction();
        //Send that data back to the client
        someSendJSONBackFunction();
    }
```

**Wrap Up**

So, am I on the right track? Has anyone implemented this kind of model and can make helpful suggestions before I dive in? Any suggestions on how I can migrate quickly from ASP?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just recommand to make the serverside side restful. We use for our sites first http://apiary.io/, that help us quick create the blueprint of the API.

Comment: looks nice, just a small warning... if you want to go that professional you could also swap technology directly. asp classic code may be easy and fast to write for simple requirements, but as soon as it gets complicated you will likely lose track. also keep in mind JS code is only executed after "all" the asp-classic code wnet through

Comment: @Vogel612 My thought is to remove the ASP all together. There is a server running Java and the client. That is it. Or at least how I see it progressing.

Comment: @Lacoz Can apiary.io handle "real-time" data transfer/long-polling?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.

If you have requirements that keep you from migrating away from ASP Classic, then you may want to look at integrating one of the (still) existing frameworks/libraries that make ASP/VBScript a more manageable development environment.

Here are three that I have links to at the moment, I know there are 2 or 3 others (that I'm aware of) but I can't recall where to find them...

- [ASP Xtreme Evolution](https://github.com/nagaozen/asp-xtreme-evolution)
- [ClASPpdev](http://code.google.com/p/claspdev/)
- [ASP-Ajaxed](http://code.google.com/p/asp-ajaxed/) (full disclosure, I recently took over this project)

If you can move to another language/framework, you may still want to use one of the libraries above to help build some of the glue that ties the old code to the new (ASP-Ajaxed has a class for emitting JSON). I'd be wary of rapidly changing/upgrading your code base only because you never know what old business rules or old bug fixes you may kill in the process.

There are a few questions with awesome answers outlining sane ways of moving your code to a new platform.